# dotnet restore error inside Docker-Container - permission denied

Tags: docker, .net-core

I used this tutorial to put my asp.net Core Application inside a Docker Container

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/quickstart-aspnet-core

But get an permission Denied inside the container:

```
10:39:02  /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.201/NuGet.targets(124,5): error : Access to the path '/src/obj' is denied. [/src/Lankoon.csproj]
10:39:02  /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.201/NuGet.targets(124,5): error :   Permission denied [/src/Lankoon.csproj]
10:39:02  The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet restore "./Lankoon.csproj"' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I tried it on a Windows10 Machine and also on an Jenkins Build Server, the result is the same.

I don't understand as which user the nuget is running?

Can anyone help?

Comment: probably you are using incorrect SDK/runtime image. Use a `dockerfile` generated by visual studio or has separate `FROM` command for runtime and SDK images

Comment: it is a image which include proxy settings, because I am behind a corporated proxy. And it includes a non root user, and that is the problem. Because our admin is a little bit of an jerk.

Comment: Could you share your `Dockerfile`?

Comment: Are you using some form of volume mount?

Comment: I solved it with a "USER root" entry in the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following line to you dockerfile

```
USER root
```

The problem inside my container was that the user was not root and dotnet restore unfortunately need root access.